# vim mapping of <c-i> in insert mode

Tags: vim

I am facing problem with mapping a key `<c-i>` in insert mode. Once this command is executed in vim, my tab is also pointing to where `<c-i>` is mapped.

Mapping command executed:

```
:inoremap <c-i> <Up>
```

Now `:imap` gives:

```
i  <Tab>     * <Up>
```

I need quick help to debug this.

Comment: `<C-I>` is `<TAB>` there is no way to get around it (same way that `<C-[>` is `<ESC>`) You can not map one without mapping the other.

Comment: See here: http://superuser.com/q/770068

Answer (score 2):

Due to the way that the keyboard input is handled internally, this unfortunately isn't generally possible today, even in GVIM. Some key combinations, like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + non-alphabetic cannot be mapped, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + letter vs. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + letter cannot be distinguished. (Unless your terminal sends a distinct *termcap* code for it, which most don't.) In insert or command-line mode, try typing the key combination. If nothing happens / is inserted, you cannot use that key combination. This also applies to `<Tab>` / `<C-I>`, `<CR>` / `<C-M>` / `<Esc>` / `<C-[>` etc. (Only exception is `<BS>` / `<C-H>`.) This is a known pain point, and the subject of various discussions on vim_dev and the #vim IRC channel.

Some people (foremost Paul LeoNerd Evans) want to fix that (even for console Vim in terminals that support this), and have floated various proposals, cp. http://groups.google.com/group/vim_dev/browse_thread/thread/626e83fa4588b32a/bfbcb22f37a8a1f8

But as of today, no patches or volunteers have yet come forward, though many have expressed a desire to have this in a future Vim 8 major release.